# T-SQL: aggregate function for calculating Nth percentile

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, statistics, analytics, percentile

I am trying to calculate the Nth percentile of all of the values in a single column in a table. All I want is a scalar, aggregate value for which N percent of the values are below. For instance, If the table has 100 rows where the value is the same as the row index plus one (1 to 100 consecutively), then I'd want this value to tell me that 95% of the values are below 95.

The PERCENTILE_CONT analytic function looks closest to what I want. But if I try to use it like this:

```
SELECT PERCENTILE_CONT(0.95) WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY ValueColumn) OVER () AS P95
```

I get one row per row in the table, all with the same value. I could use `TOP 1` to just give me one of those rows, but now I've done an additional table scan.

I am not trying to create a wizbang table of results partitioned by some other column in the original table. I just want an aggregate, scalar value.

Edit: I *have* been able to use `PERCENTILE_CONT` in a query with a `WHERE` clause. For example:

```
DECLARE @P95 INT

SELECT TOP 1 @P95 = (PERCENTILE_CONT(0.95) WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY ValueColumn) OVER ())
FROM ExampleTable
WHERE LOWER(Color) = 'blue'

SELECT @P95
```

Including the `WHERE` clause gives a different result than I got without it.

Answer (score 1):

From what I can tell, you will need to do a subquery here.  For example, to find the number of records strictly below the 95 percentile we can try:

```
WITH cte AS (
    SELECT ValueColumn,
        PERCENTILE_CONT(0.95) WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY ValueColumn) OVER () AS P95
    FROM yourTable
)

SELECT COUNT(*)
FROM cte
WHERE ValueColumn < P95;
```

Comment: Once again, I am doing another table scan. Worse, if there's a `WHERE` clause, I'll have to include it for both the main query and the subquery. Also, I do not need a subset of the table rows based on the value of the percentile.

Comment: @user1956801 `PERCENTILE_CONT` is an analytic function, which needs to iterate over the entire table in order to evaluate.  You _can't_ invoke it in the original `WHERE` clause because it won't be available yet.

Comment: So I can't, say, get the Nth percentile of all rows that match a where clause?

Comment: You would need to add a `WHERE` clause to the above CTE.

Comment: Which gets me back to having to do two table scans. If there's no aggregate method available and I can't optimize in this way, I can live with it I guess.

Comment: You are missing my point: analytic functions _can't_ be used in the `WHERE` clause, at least not in SQL Server (maybe you can in e.g. Teradata).